# Javascript nullish coalescing returns "f { [native code] }"

Tags: javascript, nullish-coalescing

I am getting an unexpected result while trying to use [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) on a return value that might be an array or might have an array as a child

```js
  const storedKeys = await getStoreKeys();

  let keys = storedKeys.keys ?? storedKeys;
  console.log(keys);
```

`console.log` output:

```
ƒ keys() { [native code] }
```

Any idea on what might be going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code for `getStoreKeys`?

Comment: If `storedKeys` is an array, then `keys` is the array method that returns an iterator of its keys, or rather, indices, because it's an array.

Comment: @kelly, I think you mean if storedKeys is an Object or Map type. May be try invoking `storedKeys.keys()` with braces

Comment: @MWaheed Arrays are objects, and thus they have a `keys` method as well.

Comment: Object has no "keys" method, at least not directly.  Sure you can do Object.keys(someObj) but you can't do someObj.keys (undefined).

Comment: Array has  [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys?retiredLocale=uk) method, which logs into console

Comment: Why do you think nullish coalescing has anything to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `storedObject` is an array, it has a built-in [`keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys?retiredLocale=uk) method (`storedObject.keys()` is equivalent to `Object.keys(storedObject)`). So the property isn't null, and it returns this function.

Use a ternary that checks if it's an array:

```
const storedKeys = Array.isArray(storedObject) ? storedObject : storedObject.keys;
```